# How to express "balancing time between several activities"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What would be the best expression to say that I have been rather busy and therefore struggling to find time for many important things such as work, school etc.

Something like: I have been trying to balance my time between school, work etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few idioms that would express the idea of not having enough time for everything.

Firstly, you could use **between** to list the various activities that are taking up your time - *Between school, work, and taking care of my children* [...]

Secondly, you could simply say **I have very little time**...but that's boring. Idioms are a lot more fun.

**I am/I have been run off my feet** is my personal favourite. It carries the connotation of rushing from one task to the next, without any time to relax or decompress between them. **There aren't enough hours in the day** is another option, specifically indicating that you're struggling to find time for all of your responsibilities.

If you're trying to show that you, specifically, are in high demand, you could say **there's only one of me**, which indicates that you feel there are contradictory demands on your time and that you can't fill all of them.

So, for your specific question - how to say that you have been very busy and struggling to find time - I would suggest something like:

**Between school, work, and astronaut training, I've been run off my feet lately.**

Answer (score 1):

The best single word I can think of is [**multitask**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multitask):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : the performance of multiple tasks at one time
>   // The job requires a person who is good at *multitasking*.

---

In your example,

> I have been struggling to multitask (between) school, work, etc.

I replaced *trying* with *struggling* to give a more definitive impression that you are not only trying to multitask the activities but finding it difficult to do so.

The use of *between* is optional. It sometimes comes after and sometimes doesn't.